# The above error occurred in the <o> component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack

I am working with React/Typescript. It was configured with webpack.
But isn't working well. Sometimes a strange error is occurred.
Error result is same as following.

```
react-dom.development.js:19527 

The above error occurred in the <o> component:
    in o (created by RegisterProfile)
    in div (created by RegisterProfile)
    in div (created by RegisterProfile)
    in div (created by RegisterProfile)
    in RegisterProfile (created by Connect(RegisterProfile))
    in Connect(RegisterProfile) (created by RegisterSteps)
    in div (created by RegisterSteps)
    in div (created by RegisterSteps)
    in div (created by RegisterSteps)
    in RegisterSteps (created by Connect(RegisterSteps))
    in Connect(RegisterSteps) (created by RegisterSteps3)
    in div (created by RegisterSteps3)
    in RegisterSteps3 (created by Connect(RegisterSteps3))
    in Connect(RegisterSteps3) (created by Route)
    in Route (created by RegularRoute)
    in RegularRoute (created by Root)
    in Switch (created by Root)
    in div (created by Root)
    in Router (created by ConnectedRouter)
    in ConnectedRouter (created by Root)
    in App (created by Connect(App))
    in Connect(App) (created by Root)
    in Provider (created by Root)
    in Root
    in ErrorBoundary
    in AppContainer

React will try to recreate this component tree from scratch using the error boundary you provided, ErrorBoundary.
```

Source code is same to following.

```
import bugsnag from '@bugsnag/js'
import bugsnagReact from '@bugsnag/plugin-react'
import * as React from 'react'
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { AppContainer } from 'react-hot-loader'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
import Root from './Root'

    const bugsnagClient = bugsnag('*********************************')
    bugsnagClient.use(bugsnagReact, React)
    const ErrorBoundary = bugsnagClient.getPlugin('react')
    const rootEl = document.getElementById('root')
    ReactDOM.render(
        <AppContainer>
            <ErrorBoundary>
                <Root/>
            </ErrorBoundary>
        </AppContainer>,
        rootEl
    )
    // Load Intercom
    declare global {
        interface Window {
            Intercom: any
        }
    }
    window.Intercom('boot', {app_id: '********'})
    // Hot Module Replacement API
    if (module.hot) {   
        module.hot.accept('./containers/Root', () => {
            const NextApp = require<{ default: typeof Root }>('./containers/Root').default
            ReactDOM.render(
                <AppContainer>
                    <ErrorBoundary>
                        <NextApp/>
                    </ErrorBoundary>
                </AppContainer>,
                rootEl
            )
        })
    }
```

I tried to fix this bug, but it is not easy. But I have not a good result.
If you have a good idea, I want to share your idea.

Comment: What is "the above error" that is mentioned? is there another error in your console? Also, react is telling the error is coming from the `RegisterProfile` component, but you haven't posted the the code for that.